# Converting list into String In Python

Tags: python, string

What is the significance of **("")** before **join** method??
What I know is that we use ***""**.join*. But here the code is working fine if though **("")** is used. Someone please explain.

```
("").join([map_s_to_t[s[i]] for i in range(len(s))])
```

## Following is my whole code...

```
class Solution:
    def isIsomorphic(self, s: str, t: str) -> bool:
        if len(set(s)) != len(set(t)):
            return False
    
        # Create a mapping of chars from  s -> t
        map_s_to_t = { s[i]: t[i] for i in range(len(s)) }
    
        # Create a new string by replacing the chars in s with t
        s_replaced_with_t = ("").join([map_s_to_t[s[i]] for i in range(len(s))])
        
        # if the replaced string is same as t , then True else False    
        return(s_replaced_with_t == t)
```

Comment: ("").join tells to concatinate strings with nothing in between. For exmaple '-'.join(['hello', 'world']) will make a string "hello-world"

Comment: The parenthesis don't really serve a purpose. They will just be ignored so you can remove them.

Comment: You can simply convert a list of string into a string by following this code:

    example = ["This","is","an","example"] 
    " ".join(example)
Output:

    "This is an example"
" " identifies that every element of the list will join by a space.

Answer (score 3):

`("").join` and `"".join` has no difference at all. Enclosing empty string `""` inside parenthesis just makes it an expression and is same as if there was no parenthesis.

For your reference, `(1)` is same as `1`, and parenthesis is mainly used for including some expression, and if you use some IDE like Pycharm/VS Code, it will show you some warning as *Redundant Parenthesis* for `("")`

Answer (score 0):

`join` concatenates words and you pass the separator, so if you have `"abc".join(['foo', 'bar'])` then the result is

**fooabcbar**

The empty string passed as a parameter specifies that nothing will be put in between the elements. The paranthesis is not necessary around the separator.

Comment: @SitiSchu "The paranthesis is not necessary around the separator." was added to the answer

Comment: Apologies, I missed that part